# Prove there do not exist prime numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that $a^3+b^3=c^3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove there do not exist prime numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that $a^3+b^3=c^3$.

From what I understand this proof requires a proof by contradiction or contrapositive...

Comment: At least one of them should be even. Therefore it is $2$. When one of those cubes is an $8$ there are no many options for the other cubes.

Comment: Simple proof, Wiles theorem (Fermat's last theorem) states that $a^3+b^3=c^3$ has no rational solution (so it has no integer solution), prime numbers are integer so there can't be any prime solutions.

Comment: Primes are more typically denoted by $p,q,r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$ So we have

$(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)=c^3$

So $(a+b)=c$ and $(a^2-ab+b^2)=c^2$

Hence $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2=a^2-ab+b^2$ which is a contradiction since it implies $3ab=0$